# Chr(195) results in different values on MAC and Windows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that checks if a particular character is present in a string. On windows this works fine, but when I run my code on MAC it turns haywire. I use Chr(195) which on windows results in capital A with tilde: Ã. On MAC the same code returns the squareroot symbol. How to go about and fix this?

Would it be best to somehow capture the OS that is running and make conditions for that, or just insert an ElseIf with a second Chr()?

The current code:

```
tempstringmais = Chr(195)
If InStr(tempstringgewas, tempstringmais) > 0 Then
     wsg.Cells(rowg, 10) = "mais"
Else
     wsg.Cells(rowg, 10) = temparray(0)
End If
```

Comment: What locale are you in?

Comment: ASCII cannot have a codepoint or code unit with the value 195. Perhaps you would like to use ChrW() once you figure out what the UTF-16 code unit is that you are using. (VBA uses the UTF-16 encoding for the Unicode character set—can't say if it was always that way but it has been for a couple decades.) [Chr() doesn't use ASCII, either.]

Comment: Try using a literal string "Ã"?

Comment: Arghh, ["Visual Basic for the Macintosh does not support Unicode strings. … Therefore, you should not use ChrW in the Macintosh environment."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465.aspx). I hope that's old information. Maybe the literal string is still a solution.

Comment: @TomBlodget You are right, it is not ASCII, I removed that from the question. Using the literal string would be the simples solution I think. Going to try and implement that.

Comment: @TomBlodget add your answer as an answer if you want.